# WinSock error #10055

Tags: python, sockets, error-handling, python-3.x, multiplatform

I have client-server architecture build in python, unfortunately the original design was made that each request to server is represented by one TCP connection and I have to send requests in large groups (20 000+) and sometimes there occurs socket error [`#10055`](http://support.ipswitch.com/kb/WSK-19980714-EM18.htm).

I've already found out how to handle it in python:

```
>>> errno.errorcode[10055]
'WSAENOBUFS'
>>> errno.WSAENOBUFS
10055
```

And build a code that is able to handle that error and reconnect (of course with little time delay to give server time to do whatever it has to do):

```
class MyConnect:
    # __init__ and send are not important here

    def __enter__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # Try several reconnects
        for i in range(0,100):
            try:
                self.sock.connect((self.address, self.port))
                break

            except socket.error as e:
                if e.errno == errno.WSAENOBUFS:
                    time.sleep(1)
                else:
                    raise

        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.sock.close()

# Pseudocode
for i in range(0,20000):
    with MyConnect(ip,port) as c:
        c.send(i)
```

My questions are:

- is there any "*good practice*" way to do this?
- is `e.errno == errno.WSAENOBUFS` multi-platform? If not so, how to make it multi-platform?

<sub>**Note**: I've tested in just on Windows yet, I need it to work on Linux too.</sub>

Comment: Are you saying you "need" to have 20000+ TCP connections to the same address/port simultaneously? You'll probably run out of ephemeral ports first. Have you considered pacing this out? Setting a max number of connections? BTW, are you closing the sockets?

Comment: By "serial" you mean you have one open connection at a time? That's not what you have in the code.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov I've eddited my question (and nuked older comment), now you have almost the exact code that I'm using

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid that's what you get for abusing TCP. It'd be much much cleaner to do all this over the same connection. Right now you have ton of overhead of connection establishment and teardowns.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov I've already made it "clean way" (give or take few minutes of debugging), but I'm still looking for a proper way to handle this error on multiple platforms and correctly react to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clogging your TCP stack with outgoing data and all the connection establishment and termination packets.

If you *have to* stick to this design, then force each connection to ***linger*** until its data has been successfully sent. That is to say, that by default, `close()` on the socket returns immediately and further delivery attempts and connection tear-down happen "in the background". You can see that doing so over 20000+ times in a tight loop can easily overwhelm the OS network stack.

The following will force your socket `close()` to hang on for up to 10 seconds trying to deliver the data:

```
import struct
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, struct.pack('ii', 1, 10))
```

Note that this is not the same as Python `socket.sendall()` - that one just passes all the bytes to the kernel .

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great answer, but I have one additional question (just out of curiosity, probably not going to implement it for real). Lets say I'll have server under extremely heavy load and I would want client to act like this `if socket.error == server_heavy_load (10055): retry after few seconds` how can I do that multiplatform (nix & windows is enough; windows is already handled by code I've originally posted).

Comment: You're going to be hitting dark corners of different TCP stacks, and there's no single standard error condition here. You'll have to test, printing out the `errno` on each platform.